# JPA annotation join based on a prior join?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to join a second table based on a join from the first annotation. I can't seem to find the right search terms to find an answer. This is being used in a Spring application.

There are essentially three tables involved, loginsActive (this Entity), Logins (joined in first @annotation), and Profiles (joined in second @annotation)... which I would like to join together:

```
  public class LoginsActiveEntity ... {

  ...
  private String loginUUID;
  ...

  // the loginEntity table being joined has fields named 
  // "loginUUID" and "profileUUID" which join to this entity on loginUUID
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "loginUUID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private LoginEntity loginEntity;

  // would like to join profileEntity table based on the profileUUID
  // from loginEntity join
  // I realize the column name is wrong, but wanted to express what I am trying to do
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "loginEntity.profileUUID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private ProfileEntity profileEntity;

  ...

}
```

Comment: Why should you want to join a table from another table as with the original table?

Comment: There are three tables involved here, an "active" table that joins a "login" table (first @annotation), which I would like to join the "profile" table (second @annotation).

Comment: Can you please post your data model?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by data model? You want to see the table definitions?

Comment: I think you need to add ProfileEntity to LoginEntity.

Comment: yes the table definitions

Comment: @TomStroemer uggh, right of course, so simple once you said it! I think I was having a slow brain day :) Thanks.